# How can I find the PPF of an LED?

Tags: led, brightness

I want to built a LED panel with a high **photon flux**, and **photon flux density**, (the LEDs have a specific wavelength) but when I start to search wich LEDs I am going to buy, all the sellers just give me:

- forward voltage;
- forward current;
- wattage of the LED.

Is there a way to know,(or at lest have an idea) of how much PPF will those LEDs produce ?

Comment: "[PPF](https://www.sanlight.com/en/about-ppf-and-ppfd/)" = photosynthetic photon flux, "PPFD" = photosynthetic photon flux density.

Comment: So, if my led is monochromatic and is in the PAR (400nm-800nm), I just need to know the photon flux, and photon flux density ? I will edit the question to turn it more clear then, but the main point remains, is it possible to mensure the photon flux with just those informations ?

Comment: All LEDs worth buying for serious work have datasheets with radiant output specified. The units used may not suit you (eg lumen) but are fully defined. If they are monochromatic LEDs then conversion to other units is 'easier'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PPF** is the number of photons (usually given in moles) that are emitted from a light source within the visible spectrum.  For a monochromatic LED, this is simple to calculate from the photon energy and the radiant flux given in the datasheet.  For a white LED, the calculation is more complex, but it can be estimated from the LED's spectrum and radiant flux.

**PPFD** is the number of photons per area once you have installed the light into some device.  It depends on the PPF of the individual LEDs, how many there are, how closely spaced they are, the angle of emission, and the distance from which you measure.  It can be numerically solved using ray tracing software (provided you can get ray data for the LEDs), but more commonly it is measured once the device is installed.

Comment: So I need to find the model of the monochromatic LED, and then find the datasheet of this LED ? Having those two informtions (Photon energy and Radiant flux), need I just mutiply one by other to find the PPF ? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Yes, you will need to look at the datasheet.  The number of photons per second is the radiant flux divided by the energy of one photon.