# Ist the radiant flux of a LED equal to the Power consumption - Power dissipated?

Tags: led, watts

After I had my question [How can I find the PPF of an LED?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/488460/how-can-i-find-the-ppf-of-an-led/488465?noredirect=1#comment1243051_488465) answred, I've started to look for some LEDs datasheets with the intention to find the radiant flux of then, but unfortunately all the datasheets that I found hadn't the radiant flux, the unique thing that I found about the radiant flux was a graph "relative radiant flux vs wavelenght" and that, as far I know, was useless for reach my goal (find the radiant flux, divide it by the photon energy of the wavelength (hc/lambda) and then find the PPF of the LED).

So, after that, I started to think about how I could find the radiant flux, and I saw that some of the datasheets had the power dissipation of the LED and, since the energy must be conserved, I started to think if I could say that the **Total power consumption  - Power dissipated = Radiant flux**, once the rest of the energy should be light, ist that right ? or am I missunderstanding something ? Please, some one help me !

Comment: Do the LED's give you light output in lumens? I think you can get from lumens to radiant power. You are right that light output = power input - heat, but that will not be fruitful in trying to achieve your goal because not everything is going to be specified under the same operating point.

Comment: If the datasheet doesn't say how bright the LED is, then it isn't the right type of LED for the application. Commercially, just a handful of LEDs are used for horticulture applications (LM301H, XLamp Horticulture, etc).  There is a reason for this, so I suggest you look at those first.

Comment: Yes. What doesn't leave as heat (long wavelength "light") leaves as light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since the energy must be conserved

Most of the electric energy is still turned into heat, not light. About 1/2 to 3/4.

The ratio between light and heat isn't a constant but gets smaller at higher power.